# Calculate width of a line depending on a number with a base of 50 %

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the width of a line depending on a number `(0 - 10)`. The width of the line should not be bigger `50 %` since I set either `left: 50%` or `right: 50%` to the line to let it move to the right or left depending on a second parameter:

```css
#line {
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

#line::after {
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="line"></div>
```

Within my example, I set the `width` to `25 %` which results in an active line in the center of the left part.

Instead, I want to use CSS `calc()` within PHP to calculate the width by a given variable:

```
width: calc(50% / <?= $number ?>);
```

The number can hold values (stepping of 1) up to `10` which should result in a full line `(50 % = 100 %)` of the left part, `5` the half and so on. `0` means no width.

I'm not sure if this is possible this way? I've tried dividing them, which seems to be the right direction but not the full deal.

Comment: can you use js?

Comment: `width: calc(5% * <?= $number ?>);` ?

Comment: What is `number`, px, %?

Comment: @Azu a simple number

Comment: @ATP works! Thanks for the hint :) Post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calc(5% * number);` should do the job:

```css
#line {
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

#line::after {
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(5% * <?= $number ?>);
  background: red;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="line"></div>
```